# Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, директории или тома в CMD

Tags: cmd

При открытии СMD сразу вижу ошибку 'Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, директории или тома'

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
>   (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   C:\Users\anton>

Иногда она появляется и при выполнении разных команд.

Comment: *При открытии СMD* В том числе если его запускать не с ярлыка из меню или ещё откуда, а непосредственно EXE?

Comment: да тоже, если непосредственно или через меню "Выполнить"

Comment: При выполнении команд эта строка может появляться несколько раз, пример:

> emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5X_API_23
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Comment: Выполните поиск по всем каталогам из %PATH% всех файлов с именем CMD и любым расширением. Проверьте содержимое autoexec.nt.

Comment: cmd нашло 3 штуки в разных папках (system32, wow64, и еще в какой-папке из папки windows).  Стоит у меня Windows 10, вроде в ней нет файла autoexec.nt (я не нашел). И автозапуск проверял - врядли из него что-то влияет, только минимально нужные приложения там.